# Python HTTPError when using urllib.request.urlopen

Tags: python

This simple piece of code (executed in Jupyter Note and PyCharm using Python 3.7) does not work on my computer but works for my colleagues:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt')
for line in fhand:
    print(line.decode().strip())
```

I get the following error message:

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-efc898e51d8c> in <module>
      1 import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
      2 
----> 3 fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt')
      4 for line in fhand:
      5     print(line.decode().strip())

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    640             response = self.parent.error(
--> 641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 
    643         return response

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    567         if http_err:
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 
    571 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    501         for handler in handlers:
    502             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 503             result = func(*args)
    504             if result is not None:
    505                 return result

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

Do you know what could be the issue? Proxy or firewall problem? As I mentioned above it actually works for my colleague who are using the same tools.

Comment: HTTP ERROR:503 may be that the web server is not providing the service. Have you checked to see if the web server is not under maintenance?

Comment: No I did to check but as I said if my colleague would execute the exact same query then it would work for them. So it makes me believe that the web server is not under maintenance. I have the feeling it is related to some settings (firewall) but I am not sure where to start.

Comment: I doubt it is a firewall error because you get HTTP Response from server. What you mean by "exact same query"? They run same Python script or just fetch same URL with curl? And can you fetch that URL with curl or postman or even a browser from your computer?

Comment: I mean they copy/paste the same Python script in their Jupyter notebooks and it works for them. Yes the url works in the browser. I am not familiar with curl and postman.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use the python requests module instead of urllib? It is much preferable.